# Drupal form: sum of each rows user input and compare to

Tags: forms

I've searched on SE and google for 2 weeks, and mostly found JavaScript or jquery solutions. I have very little knowledge of coding either. I have altered a custom Drupal module form and added a user "wager" input. I have `#element` validate (it is a positive integer) working correctly for each row of the "wager" input. It is also saving correctly to MySQL table for each "wager" input.

*Questions:* How do I sum all of the users "wager" boxes and compare `>=` to the users total available points for form validate? Is there an alternative solution to the jquery or JS? If not, how the heck would I begin to implement for that form? I can post code or screenshots if needed.

Edit: added screenshot of form:
[image]

```
 > //  * Menu callback; presents the list of all weeks and games.  *
> function mypicks_all_page($league) {   return theme('mypicks_all',
> array('league' => $league)); }
> 
> 
> /**  * Display the list of all weeks and games.  * The user would pick
> a week link from here to make their weekly picks.  */ function
> theme_mypicks_all($variables) {   global $_PICKEM_MY_LEAGUES;   global
> $user;  /*******************blakestart*/
> 
> /********blakeend*******************/   $league =
> $variables['league'];
> 
 >   // Param check: user must be a member of this league to continue.  
 > if ( !is_my_league($league) ) {
  >     return drupal_not_found();   }
  > 
   >   drupal_set_title(t('My Picks - %user_name', array('%user_name' =>
 > $user->name)), PASS_THROUGH);
   > 
       >   $breadcrumb = drupal_get_breadcrumb();   $breadcrumb[] =
       > l($league->name, 'pickem/' . $league->lid);  
        > drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
    > 
    >   $teams = get_teams(array('gameset_id' => $league->gsid));   $games =
      > get_games(array('league_id' => $league->lid), array('by_week' => 1,
  > 'order_by' => 'week_ended, g.gamestart, g.gid'));
    > 
  > 
      >   $header = array(t('Week'), t('Games'));   $rows = array();   foreach
  > ($games as $wid => $weeks_games) {
    >     $cols = array();
 >     $current_week = '';
 >     foreach ($weeks_games as $gid => $game) {
   >         
   >         
     >         
    > 
    > 
    >       // Figure out the matchup operator.
 >       if ($game->neutral_venue == 1) {
  >         $matchup = "vs ";
     >       }
     >       else {
 >         $matchup = "@";
>       }
> 
>       // The first column should be the week number link.
 >       if ( count($cols) == 0 ) {
>         $cols[] = array('data' => l(t('Week&nbsp;%wk_number', array
('%wk_number' =>     $game->wk_number)),
> "pickem/$league->lid/mypicks/" . $wid, array('html' => TRUE)), 'class'
> => 'week');
>       }
>       $current_week .= '<div class="picks-float">' . $teams[$game->v_id]->short_name .     '<br/>' . $matchup .
> $teams[$game->h_id]->short_name . '</div>';
>     }
>     $cols[] = $current_week;
>     $rows[] = $cols;   }   return theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' =>        $rows, 'attributes' => array('class' =>
 > array('pickem-mypicks-all')))); }
> 
> 
> function mypicks_week_form($form, &$form_state, $league, $week) {  
> global $user;  global $wager;
> 
>   
> 
>   $form = build_picks_week_form($form, $form_state, $league, $week,
> $user, $wager);   return $form; }
> 
> 
> function theme_mypicks_week_form($variables) {   global $user;
 > 
 > 
 >      $form = $variables['form'];   $league =
 > league_load($form['league_id']['#value']);
> 
>   // Drupal sets the default timezone to be the user's   //if
> available, otherwise, the system's.   $timezone =
> date_default_timezone_get();
> 
>   $header = array();   $header[] = t('Matchup');   if
 > ($league->scoring_engine->features['with_confidence'] == 1) {
>     $header[] = array('data' => t('Confidence'), 'class' => 'confidence-pts');   }          $header[] = t('Status');   $header[] =
> array('data'=>t('Game time'), 'title'=> t('Timezone is @timezone',
 > array('@timezone' => $timezone)));  if
 > ($league->scoring_engine->features['with_spread'] == 1){   $header[] =
 > array('data'=>t('Wager'), 'title'=>'This is Wager column');  }   $rows
 > = array();   $last = count(element_children($form['games']));   $count = 0;   foreach      (element_children($form['games']) as $gid) {
 >     $count++;
>     $cols = array();
 > 
 >     if (isset($form['games'][$gid]['pick'])) {
 >       if ($form['games'][$gid]['pick']['#default_value'] == '') {
  >         $cols[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['pick']),  'class' => 'no-pick');
  >       }
 >       else {
 >         $cols[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['pick']));
  >       }
 >     }
 >     else {
  >       $cols[] = drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['pick_v_score']) . drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['pick_h_score']);
 >     }
 > 
 >     // Render confidence boxen
 >     if ($league->scoring_engine->features['with_confidence'] == 1) {
 >       if($form['games'][$gid]['confidence']['#default_value'] == '') {
 >         $cols[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['confidence']),
 > 'class'=>'no-pick');
 >       } else {
 >         $cols[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['confidence']));
 >       }
 >     }
 > 
 >     $cols[] = drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['pick_status']);
 > 
 >     $cols[] = drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['gamestart']);
 >     
 > 
 >     $cols[] = drupal_render($form['games'][$gid]['wager']);
 > 
 > 
 >   
 >     $rows[] = $cols;   }
 > 
 >   $output = $league->scoring_engine->description;   $output .= '<p>' .
 > t('Game time is represented in the @timezone timezone.',
 > array('@timezone' => $timezone)) . '</p>';   $output .= theme('table',
 > array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows, 'attributes' =>
 > array('class' => array('pickem-mypicks-week'))));   $output .=
  > drupal_render_children($form);   return $output; }
 > 
 > 
 > 
 > 
  >   
 > 
 > 
 > function mypicks_week_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {   $league =
 > league_load($form_state['values']['league_id']);   if
 > (($league->scoring_engine->features['with_confidence'] == 1)) {
 >     $conf_values = array();
>     $max_conf = count($form_state['values']['games']);
>     foreach ($form_state['values']['games'] as $gid => $pick) {
> 
>       // Skip empty confidence values.
>       if ($pick['confidence'] == '') {
>         continue;
>       }
> 
>       // Out of range confidence numbers
>       if (!is_numeric($pick['confidence']) || $pick['confidence'] < 1 || $pick['confidence'] > $max_conf) {
>         form_set_error('games][' . $gid . '][confidence', t('Confidence point must be a number from 1 to %max.', array('%max' =>
> $max_conf)));
>       }
> 
>       // Duplicate confidence numbers
>       if (isset($conf_values[$pick['confidence']])) {
>         form_set_error('games][' . $gid . '][confidence', t('Confidence point %pt already used.', array('%pt' =>
> $pick['confidence'])));
>       }
>       $conf_values[$pick['confidence']] = TRUE;
>     
>     
> 
> 
>    
>          
>       }}}    /**  * Implements hook_form_alter().  */ function webform_calc_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {   if
> ($form_id == 'mypicks-week-form') {
>     $form['#validate'][] = 'webform_calc_validate';   } } function webform_calc_validate($form, &$form_state) {  
> switch($form_state['input']['details']['page_num']) {
>     case '1':
>       $bet = $form_state['input']['submitted']['wager'];
>       
>       
>       $totalbet = $wager + $wager;
 >       form_set_value(
>         $form['submitted']['totalbet'], $totalbet, $form_state);
>       break;
>     case '2':
>       $totalbet = $form_state['storage']['submitted'][4];
>       $form_state['webform']['component_tree']['children']
>         [11]['value'] = 'Total bet: ' . $totalbet; 
>       break;   }   return $form; } 
> 
> function mypicks_week_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {   global
> $user;
> 
> 
>   $league = league_load($form_state['values']['league_id']);   $week =
> week_load($form_state['values']['week_id']);  
> $form_state['values']['wager'] = array();
>   
>   
> 
>   // You should not be able to save picks after lockup.   if
> ($league->pick_lock == PICKEM_PICK_LOCK_WEEK && $week->week_started ==
> 1) {
>     drupal_set_title(t('%week_name picks are locked.', array('%week_name' => $week-      >wk_name)), PASS_THROUGH);
>     return t("You cannot change your picks now.");   }
> 
>   
> 
>   
>  
>   
> 
>   // Check and see if the user wants to save to all their leagues that
> use the same gameset.   $save_for_these_leagues = array();   if (
> $form_state['values']['apply_to_all_leagues'] == 1 ) {
>     $save_for_these_leagues = get_my_leagues($league->gsid);   }   else {
>     $save_for_these_leagues[] = $league;   }
> 
  >   foreach ($save_for_these_leagues as $l) {
>     // Only save for league using the same scoring system.
>     $success = TRUE;
>     if ($l->scoring_type == $league->scoring_type) {
>       foreach ($form_state['values']['games'] as $gid => $pick) {
>         $pick['gid'] = $gid;
>         if (set_pick($user->uid, $l, $pick, 'user') != TRUE) {
>           $success = FALSE;
>         }
>       }
> 
>    
>  
>      if ($success) {
>         
>          
>   
>            
 >        drupal_set_message(t('The picks have been saved for league <i>%league</i>.', array('%league' => $l->name)));
>       
 >       }
 >     }   } } //
```

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to do that calculation? Before or after submitting?

Assuming you want to do it before submitting the form, you can use the [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to set a custom submit function where you will receive the values from the form and do whatever you need with them. Something like:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == "YOUR_FORM_ID") {
        $form['#submit'][] = "_YOUR_MODULE_do_calculations";
    }
}

function _YOUR_MODULE_do_calculations($form, &$form_state) {

     $total = 0;
     if (isset($form_state['values']['YOUR_FIELD_1'])
      && isset($form_state['values']['YOUR_FIELD_2'])
      && isset($form_state['values']['YOUR_FIELD_3'])) {

        // Sum up values, save in DB or anything you need

     }
}
```

Comment: awesome I haven't stumbled across anything like that . I will try it out and get back ASAP. thanks for your quick response.

Comment: It seems like im almost there now with that. I should have specified, I am trying to sum all the 'wager' fields and compare to the current users total points, * and spit out a drupal_set_message(t('you dont have enough points')) if the SUM_of_Wagers > total_points. So would this still be form_alter on #submit or #validate ? Thanks !